# Android emulator screen rotates while calling

Tags: android

I have created an android app which has a call function in it.
When i try calling on android emulator/ Android Virtual device, the screen rotates. Why does the screen rotates, and please suggest ways so that screen stops rotating.
Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Without a [MCVE], it's going to be difficult for anyone to tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your emulator has been confing wrong, you can fix it to start-up the device in Landscape or Portrait mode, modifications be made in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager. Open the Virtual Device Manager, and click the Edit pencil:

[image: Select edit]

[image: Choose your mode]

If you're sure that only want an unique mode, need put this inside the Android manifest file of your project, find the activity declaration of whose you want to fix the orientation and add the following piece of code:

for landscape orientation:

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

for portrait orientation:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Hope you serve, cheers.

Comment: Thanks that works for me!